# wifi networks not showing up in ubuntu14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek, ubuntu-drivers

I installed ubuntu 14.04, my wifi driver is **realtek 8723be**. The wifi networks are not showing even I have installed the correct drivers and have `wlan` connection when i type `ifconfig` in terminal.

Also I have tried methods of editing `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` but it also does not help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list` terminal command.